# Element not found in selenium webdriver were given correct xpath

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I'm new to selenium just now started to learn. I'm using `chromdriver` for my program.

**program:**

```
package WebDriver;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class SamplePjt {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {


        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\YATHEESH\\Desktop\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver a = new ChromeDriver ();
        a.get("http://cspportal.protechsoftsystems.com");
        a.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='a_sectionSignIn1']")).click();
        a.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='txtUserName1']")).sendKeys("auto1@gboxz.com");
        a.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='txtPinText1']")).sendKeys("test");
        a.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='Section_SignIn_1']/div[5]/div[2]/input")).click();
        a.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        a.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='txtLine1Addr']")).sendKeys("123 easy st");
        a.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='txtCityAddr']")).sendKeys("Little Rock");
        a.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='txtStateAddr']")).sendKeys("Arkansas");
        a.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='txtZipCode']")).sendKeys("72211");
        a.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='txtOfficePhoneNumb']")).sendKeys("9999999999");
    a.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='divMailingAddress']/div[4]/button")).click();
    }
}
```

I got `No such element found`, while program read after time out - even though i gave correct xpath,

```
a.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='txtLine1Addr']")).sendKeys("123 easy st");
        a.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='txtCityAddr']")).sendKeys("Little Rock");
        a.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='txtStateAddr']")).sendKeys("Arkansas");
        a.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='txtZipCode']")).sendKeys("72211");
        a.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='txtOfficePhoneNumb']")).sendKeys("9999999999");
    a.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='divMailingAddress']/div[4]/button")).click();
```

Please give me solution for this issue.

Comment: Generally there are two causes for that.  The element you are looking for is in a frame or iframe, or the element loads slowly.

Comment: For which element are you getting this exception?

Comment: can you share the code of the html page

Comment: @lost As shown in the code, the page is available at this URL: http://cspportal.protechsoftsystems.com

Answer (score 0):

You said you are looking for this **xpath** at this webpage: view-

http://cspportal.protechsoftsystems.com/

I opened this page and **got redirected** to:

http://cspportal.protechsoftsystems.com/Applications/ServiceProvider/Home/Home.aspx

and after doing a quick check of the source code (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> for `txtLine1Addr`) it simply does not find anything with that id.

so your xpath is looking for an id that **is not present in source code** of the page. But I see that there is a kind of slideshow happening and other javascript stuff on that page, is it possible that the html that you want to test is **asynchronously loaded**? If so you would have to wait for the presence of those elements first

Comment: where will this element be shown exactly? Maybe you will have to click something before this appears?

Comment: div class=" col-sm-6 controls">
        <input id="txtLine1Addr" class="form-control" type="text" valuetype="address" validationmessage="Invalid Address" data-validation-required-message="Address is empty" maxlength="50" required="" datafield="Line1Addr" placeholder="Street Address, P.O Box" data-validation-callback-callback="UtilityScripts.ValidateField" controlsection="HeadAdress" messageloadeddata-validation-required-message="true" messageloadedvalidationmessage="true" jquery18303710732529836557="43" fillervalue="" aria-invalid="false"></input>

Comment: this is wer am getting error a.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='txtLine1Addr']")).sendKeys("123 easy st");

Comment: Where can I find this form where there is this address input field? I don't find it

Comment: after login process, it will navigates to Address info page in that have address fields for that i have " a.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='txtLine1Addr']")).sendKeys("123 easy st"); "